# mysql query to get first 200 characters

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a long text But while showing I  only want to show the 200 characters  How to query only for 200 characters out a long text  that is saved in mysql table as data type as 'TEXT';  or do I need need to save the text by slicing the text upto 200 charcters and saving it in another column ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SELECT LEFT(column,200) FROM table` or substring the result after selecting it from the database.

Comment: I don't exactly know but it looks like that LEFT could be a little bit better: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,265979,266043#msg-266043

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(colname,1,200) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [`SUBSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function will accomplish this:

```
select substr(col, 1, 200) from table_name;
```